# python :appending to a list from 2 csv files

Tags: python, csv

I have 2 csv files that i want to append to a list but I can't seem to get it to work?
the outcome is a blank list.
don't know if this is possible or if you have to do them individually, any help is much appreciated

```
import csv

file1=open("12A.csv")
class1=csv.reader(file1)

file2=open("12B.csv")
class2=csv.reader(file2)

classes=[]
for column in class1 and class2:
    classes.append(column[0,2])
print(classes)
```

Comment: So you are trying to join the lines of two csv files such that line 1 from both files is merged into element 1  of classes?

Comment: basically i have 2 csv files with a set of names(one for each class), i want to append them to a list so i can print them all out into a textbox.

Comment: you should use `zip` not `and`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to use follow methodology:

```
 for cola,colb in zip(class1,class2):
       classes.append([cola,colb])
 print classes
```

or simply

```
classes = zip(class1,class2)
```

depending on the format you want the result to be in.

In short this is what zip does:

> This function returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains
>   the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables

You can take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) for further reference about zip function

Comment: not quite sure what this does but it works so thanks XD

Comment: I will add some reference if you want to know what's going on

Comment: @TomLowbridge don't forget to mark the answer accepted if you are satisfied with the solution. This will avoid this question being marked as unanswered. Also I have added explanation